# apex_debug messages after attaching to an APEX session using apex_session.attach

Tags: oracle, debugging, oracle-apex

I'm using Oracle Apex 22.1. I have a page that starts a job in the background to process data.
The job attaches to the current APEX session using an `APEX_SESSION.ATTACH` call.
Now after attaching to the job, I want to be able to see the debug messages that are generated by this job in the Debug messages.
But they dont seem to appear in the regular debug window opened from the page.
Is there any way to see these messages?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you seeing them in the APEX_DEBUG_MESSAGES view? Have you turned on debugging within your job?

Comment: I assume you mean have I enabled debugging? If so, yes. The code in the job makes a `apex_debug.enable(apex_debug.c_log_level_app_trace);` call and then makes a `apex_debug.trace` call.

Comment: I'm not seeing the messages when I query the `APEX_DEBUG_MESSAGES` view from the apex developer.

Comment: Actually, if it's a background job then APEX debugging probably isn't going to be relevant - since there is no associated APEX session. You can create one programmatically, but maybe it's better using your local PL/SQL instrumentation?

Comment: While I agree in principle, I have to point out that the background job attaches to a bonafide APEX session. So where to the debug messages actually go to? Unless this is specifically disallowed by `apex_debug`, shouldn't the debug messages be actually visible somewhere instead of being "lost"?

Comment: How have you confirmed this? How are you launching the job? Does it have a app_session value?

Comment: Yes. The job PLSQL has this part in it which attaches to the APEX session, `apex_session.attach(p_app_id => ' || v('APP_ID') || ', p_page_id => ' || v('APP_PAGE_ID') || ', p_session_id => ' || v('APP_SESSION') || ');`. Post this in the same PLSQL code, it enables the debug. I can confirm that it attaches to the session because from the front-end, I can see the debug getting enabled once the job is started. It can only mean that the job has attached to the session and enabled the debugging. Its only the messages that dont show up.

Comment: It will probably help if you add further detail to the original post as to how you invoke the job, and how you associate it with the session. Something to consider: if you're running v('APP_SESSION') within the unattached job, this would return null.